# Bioroid 2.0 Ice: can runner spend 2 clicks more than once?

Tags: android-netrunner

The text of the Heimdall 2.0 (https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03015) says: "The Runner can spend 2 clicks to break up to 2 subroutines on Heimdall 2.0".

Is this a one-time use perk or something the runner can use several times, for example, spending 2 clicks twice (as two different actions)?

Comment: As both answers so far point out, this is actually a common question across all the Bioroid ice, not really specific to Heimdall. It is theoretically possible for even Viktor 2.0 to end up with more than 2 subroutines, for example with Sub Boost or Wetwork Refit.

Comment: Yep. I used Heimdal 2.0 as an example.

Comment: It's worth noting that the runner would need to have gained an extra click somewhere, since the runner starts with 4 clicks, and must spend one of them to start the run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The runner can use this option multiple times, provided he/she has enough clicks to spend, same as with 1.0 model bioroids. Main difference from 1.0 is that runner cannot spend just one click to break exactly one sub with 2.0 bioroids.

Answer (score 1):

You can spend *exactly* two clicks to break *up to* two of Heimdall 2.0's subroutines. If you have fewer than two unspent clicks when you encounter him, you cannot spend clicks to break subroutines and will have to break them some other way, or let the subroutines fire. In theory, you could spend two more clicks to break the one remaining subroutine, if you had gained an extra click and had four left at the start of the run.

N.B.: The 1.0 line of bioroid ice lets you spend clicks to break subroutines at a rate of 1:1.

Comment: I think "exactly two clicks" would be more clear than "a minimum of two clicks", since three meets the criterion of the second version but not the first.